# Button click on a table Cell doesn't return the function value to only first row

Tags: html, reactjs, button

I am new to react and html, we are currently developing a front page where in user can key in some values and based on which REST API (basically a backend service) would return the result.

We are capturing this result onto a table with 7 columns.

Last column i.e., column 7 will have a button which on a click, will invoke another REST API with different params and result, should display a value and also give another button option.

Currently I have below 2 issues:

1) When I click the button on any row, always the text is being displayed only on column 7 of row 1 (even though my state variables show correct results). Not sure what might be the issue. Can someone please point it out?

Code of column 5:

```html
<td>
  <className='xx' id='clm5'>
    <button className='yy' type='submit' value={identifier of the row} onclick=this.function()> Display</button>
    <p id='clm5' />
</td>
```

Function:

```js
document.getElementById('clm5').innerHTML = Text to display;
```

2) I need to have an additional reload button along with text as stated in point 1. How can I get this achieved?

Any help over these is much appreciated

Comment: can you show the code how you render the 7columns with .map ?

Comment: In your code you have two elements with the same id. It should be unique. And in you script is "clmn5" and html is "clm5"

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys...I have changed the ids and that has sorted the issue number 1